# Possible to communicate visual messages over long distances using telescopes and mirrors?

Tags: optics, atmospheric-science, telescopes

A thought experiment question: From both a theoretical and engineering standpoint, would it be possible to transmit visual messages over long distances on the surface of the Earth via a series of telescope stations?

The first telescope in the chain, mounted atop a tower, would be focused on a large sign containing a message (for example, "Do you have any flour?"), let's say 10 miles distant. The image from the first telescope would then be projected through its eyepiece onto a surface, which the second telescope in the chain 10 miles away would be focused upon, and so on all the way through the network.

Assuming clear and stable weather, could a network of telescopes used in this manner communicate messages at the speed of light around the globe? Or would there be significant image degradation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signals have been relayed optically through free space historically. For example the [optical telegraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_telegraph) or semaphore system used in 19th C. France. It didn't operate at the speed of light because the time taken to relay a message at each station (reproduce the received signal from one side to a transmitted signal on the other side) is much greater than the speed of light delay from one station to the next.

> The image from the first telescope would then be projected through its eyepiece onto a surface, which the second telescope in the chain 10 miles away would be focused upon, and so on all the way through the network.

The issue with this design is that you are relying on the light from the original image being relayed through multiple projections and reprojections to the final receiver. Practically, each time a receiving telescope projects an image onto a screen, that image will be substantially (10's or 100's of times) dimmer than the original that the telescope is viewing. It wouldn't take many such relays before the image becomes too dim to be distinguished from background light.

Comment: Thank you - this would also seem to rule out observing images in real time that have been transmitted over hundreds of miles (like a low-tech TV!). Unless a way could be found to brighten the image en route to avoid significant dimming. Perhaps with large mirrors?